# Benefit of constexpr on non-changing expressions

Tags: c++, constexpr

So I understand that the use of `constexpr` in C++ is for defined expressions that are be evaluated at compile time, and more obviously to declare a variable or function as a constant expression. My confusion comes from understanding any benefits of using it for simple functions that will not change.

Suppose you have a function to simply square a value...

```
int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

Typically that will never change, or be overridden, however, I've seen people say that it would be better practice to instead define it as...

```
constexpr int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

To me, this seems like such a trivial change. Can anyone enlighten me on serious advantages of declaring such simple expressions as `constexpr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of that change is that whenever `x` is known at compile time, result of `square` could be used to initialize `constexpr` variables or as a template argument.